# How to export a JavaScript object using module.exports in an npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I published an npm package. The directory structure is something like the following:

```
my-package
└── js/script.js
└── index.js
```

The `js/script.js` file contains an object that is the name of my library, lets say `elephant`. Something like this:

```
var elephant = {
    function_1: function() {
        ...
    },
    function_2: function() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my `index.js` file, I am exporting this like so:

```
import { elephant } from "./js/script.js";

module.exports = elephant;
```

Once I published and installed my package, I tried to pull it in my project using the following line of code:

```
const elephant = require('my-package');
elephant.function_1();
elephant.function_2();
```

However, unfortunately when I run my server (in a Vue project), I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

I assume this is referring to the third line in the `index.js` file. How can I fix this issue? How do I export my object variable and use it in my node project? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried swapping `var elephant = ` to `export elephant =` in your `script.js`? I'm expecting the code-splitting is failing here... if not, have you tried console.log() all the way up?

Comment: @MatthewSpence Yes, that fails and I get `Module parse failed`

Answer (score 2):

You can't mix `import` and `module.exports`

use `export default elephant`  instead of `module.exports = elephant;`

Comment: The import works but if I call a function in node project, ie, `elephant.function_1()`, I get this error: `"TypeError: elephant.function_1 is not a function"`.